# Table Of Contents Web Part displaying deleted site

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have inserted a Table of Contents web part onto a page and made sure it is not displaying hidden sites, and is only showing 1 level of information. Fine.

Strangely it is displaying a site that we deleted months ago. The link is unclickable in the Table of contents. I am 100% certain that the site no longer exists, I have run searches and tried to go straight to its URL (we have a standard for these) and cannot find it anywhere. 
Any ideas how I can remove this from the table of contents?

Cheers.

Comment: Is it possible for you to query the deleted site in PowerShell using the command [Get-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807%28v=office.14%29.aspx)? If you can query it, perhaps you can retry deleting it using the PowerShell commmand [Remove-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607890%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: If there is a manual entry in the Navigation settings of the site, then it will remain even though the site is deleted. The Table of Contents uses the navigation settings of a site to determine what to display. I suggest the OP look into the navigation settings of the site in which the Table of Contents resides.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, realized that my local navigation (Site Settings - navigation - current navigation) had manual entries and the Table of Contents was pulling the entry from that.

Comment: This does offer a possible solution to the question, in fact.
If there is a manual entry in the Navigation settings of the site, then it will remain even though the site is deleted.  The Table of Contents uses the navigation settings of a site to determine what to display.  I suggest the OP look into the navigation settings of the site in which the Table of Contents resides.